# Visual studio error: Error (active) E0254 type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio says:

> Error (active)    E0254   type name is not allowed

What did I do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber
{
    public:
    float Real;
    float Virtual;

    ComplexNumber Addition(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real + b.Real;
        Result.Virtual = a.Virtual + b.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    ComplexNumber Subtraction(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real - b.Real;
        Result.Virtual = a.Virtual - b.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    ComplexNumber Struct(float a, float b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a;
        Result.Virtual = b;
        return Result;
    }

    ComplexNumber Multiplication(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real * b.Real - a.Virtual * b.Virtual;
        Result.Virtual = a.Real * b.Virtual + a.Virtual * b.Real;
        return Result;
    }

    ComplexNumber Division(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        float q = (b.Real*b.Real + b.Virtual*b.Virtual);
        Result.Real = (a.Real * b.Real + a.Virtual * b.Virtual)/q;
        Result.Virtual = (-a.Real * b.Virtual + a.Virtual * b.Real)/q;
        return Result;
    }

    ComplexNumber Square(ComplexNumber a)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real*a.Real - a.Virtual*a.Virtual;
        Result.Virtual = 2*a.Real*a.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    string Display(ComplexNumber a)
    {
        return to_string(a.Real) + to_string(a.Virtual) + "i";
    }
};

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber a, b;
    cin >> a.Real >> a.Virtual >> b.Real >> b.Virtual;
    string str = ComplexNumber.Display(ComplexNumber.Addition(a, b));
    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding random garbage text, you should have added actual information helping to find the problem. For example, which line of code did the error message point to?

Comment: Alternatively, you could have improved the code to text ratio by creating a [mre] and include the only the smallest possible amount of code that is needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComplexNumber` is a name of the class, so you cannot use its member via `.` operator like `ComplexNumber.Display` and `ComplexNumber.Addition`.

You should spedify a name of variables, not a name of a class, before `.` operator like:

```
string str = a.Display(a.Addition(a, b));
```

In this case it looks better to declare static functions and use `::` to access them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber
{
    public:
    float Real;
    float Virtual;

    static ComplexNumber Addition(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real + b.Real;
        Result.Virtual = a.Virtual + b.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    static ComplexNumber Subtraction(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real - b.Real;
        Result.Virtual = a.Virtual - b.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    static ComplexNumber Struct(float a, float b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a;
        Result.Virtual = b;
        return Result;
    }

    static ComplexNumber Multiplication(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real * b.Real - a.Virtual * b.Virtual;
        Result.Virtual = a.Real * b.Virtual + a.Virtual * b.Real;
        return Result;
    }

    static ComplexNumber Division(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        float q = (b.Real*b.Real + b.Virtual*b.Virtual);
        Result.Real = (a.Real * b.Real + a.Virtual * b.Virtual)/q;
        Result.Virtual = (-a.Real * b.Virtual + a.Virtual * b.Real)/q;
        return Result;
    }

    static ComplexNumber Square(ComplexNumber a)
    {
        ComplexNumber Result;
        Result.Real = a.Real*a.Real - a.Virtual*a.Virtual;
        Result.Virtual = 2*a.Real*a.Virtual;
        return Result;
    }

    static string Display(ComplexNumber a)
    {
        return to_string(a.Real) + to_string(a.Virtual) + "i";
    }
};

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber a, b;
    cin >> a.Real >> a.Virtual >> b.Real >> b.Virtual;
    string str = ComplexNumber::Display(ComplexNumber::Addition(a, b));
    cout << str;
}
```